# Agrupar registros e criar coluna no SQL Firebird

Tags: sql, firebird

Tenho os seguintes registros:

```
|MAQUINA|LOTECA| DTPOST |SEXOCAR|QTDEPIN|
|17 MAQ |602121|02/04/20|Fêmeas | 9300  |
|17 MAQ |602121|02/04/20|Machos | 9600  |
|17 MAQ |602121|02/04/20|Fêmeas | 100   |
|18 MAQ |509119|30/03/20|Machos | 2000  |
|18 MAQ |509119|30/03/20|Fêmeas | 9600  |
|18 MAQ |509119|01/04/20|Fêmeas | 6300  |
```

Gostaria que ficasse dessa forma:

```
|MAQUINA|LOTECA| DTPOST |FEMEAS| MACHOS|
|17 MAQ |602121|02/04/20| 9400 | 9600  |
|18 MAQ |509119|30/03/20| 9600 | 2000  |
|18 MAQ |509119|01/04/20| 6300 | NULL  |
```

Estou montando o SQL:

```
select MAQUINA,LOTECA,DTPOST,SEXOCAR,SUM(QTDEPIN) AS QTDE FROM TB_TESTE 
GROU BY MAQUINA,LOTECA,DTPOST,SEXOCAR
ORDER BY MAQUINA,DTPOST
```

Minha dúvida é como criar as colunas e juntar as informações.

Comment: Pesquise por PIVOT https://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/transformar-linhas-em-colunas-no-firebird/455967

Comment: Não precisa colocar "resolvido" no título. Sei que é comum em muitos fóruns, mas aqui funciona diferente. No seu caso, como vc mesmo encontrou a solução, basta usar o campo de respostas abaixo (o textarea "Sua Resposta"), e depois basta [marque-a como aceita](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052), isso já é o suficiente para indicar que foi resolvido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi da seguinte forma:

```
select MAQUINA,LOTECA,DTPOST,
 SUM(case when SEXOCARR = 'Fêmeas' then QTDEPINT else 0 end) as FEMEAS,
 SUM(case when SEXOCARR = 'Machos' then QTDEPINT else 0 end) as MACHOS FROM TB_TESTE 
GROU BY MAQUINA,LOTECA,DTPOST
ORDER BY MAQUINA,DTPOST
```